# Session timeout in web applications

Tags: session, timeout

The session timeout in web applications typically denotes the idle time - i.e. the period of time when the user doesn't work with the application.

Now, what if there is an automated script written that posts a request every 5 minutes - wouldn't that user's session go on endlessly? This being the case, won't this approach heavily load the application affecting its performance in the long run?

Answer (score 4):

Running an automated call to the server, say via an AJAX request, *will* keep the session alive.  Typically that's the point though.  An interesting side effect of this is that if the request happens predictably and regularly, you can use it as a "ping" to determine if the user's browser is still open.  If one or two pings are missed, you can close the session earlier and actually free up resources sooner than if you just let the session time out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and Yes.

This is why if you're going to write an application for the web, you really want to find a way to implement it without using server side sessions.  Usually, you will be able to find ways to implement the same functionality using cookies -- then the session data is client-side so who cares if they stay active permanently.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar for an application that relies heavily on session data.

What I did was set the IIS timeout to a relatively low number, say 10 minutes, then have a timed AJAX call that pings a blank page every 5 minutes.

This overhead on this is actually fairly low, as all you are doing is requesting a blank page, and if a person closes their browser, the session ends in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You want to keep session as small as possible. That said, if everyone starts doing that, of course it will load your application, with(out) session. If you think your users are compelled to do that, consider why, as either your application is missing an important feature or is forcing them into something.

Now, regardless of that, if you are expecting lots of users to be active at the same time, so much than a single server won't do, then you would will end up having the session out of process. If the session is in Sql Server, it is just saved data, so in that case we wouldn't be talking about memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I guess "It Depends"  The first question you should ask yourself is whether you even need session.

If you have an automated process, my guess is that you don't really need to use session.

In that case, either turn it off or don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your session table would be a little bit larger, but on the other hand you won't be tearing down and recreating the session.  I don't see how this would "heavily load" the application.  I suppose it would depend on the application itself and how much memory is used to maintain session state.

Answer (score 0):

It would allow the use's session to go on endlessly, as long as they have their browser open.  If need to keep a session alive for an extended period of time, you could also track the sessions via the DB and not in memory.

Also, if you are worried about the indefinite open session, you could implement a timeout from when the session opened and if there is an extended idle time.